# Set Bounty hangs on StackOverflow, tried from 3 different browsers

Tags: bug, bounty

I've never resorted to bounties before, but decided to try it for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257647).

But after filling out the dialogs, it seems to just hang and not post the bounty.

On the very last step in the popup dialog box, when I click the "Start Bounty" button to submit it, the button grays out like it's doing something, but then never finishes.  If I view the question in another browser, it's not marked as having a bounty.

What I've tried / considered:

- I've tried in all three browsers (Safari, Firefox and Chrome)
- I'm logged in
- The question is eligible and has the "start a bounty" link
- I do have enough points to set a bounty
- I'd still be over 500 points even after the deduction
- The "reason" radio button I chose was "To get more attention"
- I added a custom message "Looking for fix or alt code"
- I did a quick re-read of the help page and search on Google
- It's not something I want to try on another question, given the cost
- This is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257647)

Comment: @MartijnPieters changed this from "support" to "bug", so presumably it's broken?  Are others having this problem?  Or is there something specific to my question / bounty choices?

Comment: There are two options here: Either this is something local to your network (a firewall blocking the request because of a keyword somewhere has been seen before, usually when entering SQL commands but also in other cases), or there is a bug on the Stack Exchange site.

Comment: But noone else has chimed in, so I'd err on the side of it being a network-level issue on your side.

Comment: I tried again today with *no comments* and it seemed to work.  Really odd, my network seems pretty stable, and to have it not work on 3 browsers...

Comment: Then something on your network didn't like the look of *Looking for fix or alt code* for some strange reason. It won't be the first time [network firewalls decide they don't like a request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43466/rejection-of-text-containing-sql-statements). Using `https://` may help.

Comment: I had the same thing. Could only do it without a comment. The comment was very innocent "Deserves more than one vote". This clearly is a bug.

Comment: I just experienced the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @PeterAlfvin it's nice to know it wasn't just me.  I don't know how to get the Stack folks to investigate further, I rarely use the bounty feature.